# 'roundoff error was detected' R integrate()

Tags: r, optimization, integrate

18 hours into a simulation I hit an error in the `integrate()` function:

```
roundoff error was detected
```

The call is

```
integrate(..., abs.tol = 1e-10, rel.tol = 1e-12)
```

I had also parallelised my code over 8 cores so it will be time consuming to reproduce the error. Does anyone know what this error means? Any tips on debugging inside a `parfor` loop? There would have been > thousands of unproblematic integrations before the error occurred.

The integral is occurring inside a call to `optim()` so I require high accuracy to ensure a smooth function to optimise.

Comment: what about wrapping the code with `try`

Comment: Hard to tell, really. There's a bunch of google hits on that, so maybe one of these will give you a hint. E.g. this [thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problem-following-an-R-bug-fix-to-integrate-td4671689.html) suggests increasing tolerance (if you can afford it, of course; the computation will also be faster to reproduce).